# Reading from an Access Database c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to read from an access database and put the results in a listbox. Here is the code I have, it keeps telling me that "No data exists for the row/column. I have data entered in a Column named "GroupName" and have data in a column named "RandomNumber" in the table "GroupNames"

```
db = new OleDbConnection();
db.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + fileName;
db.Open();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM GroupNames ORDER BY RandomNumber ASC";

cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, db);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

lblist.Text = (string)rdr["GroupName"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lblist.Items.Clear();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    //lblist.Text += (string)rdr["GroupName"];
    lblist.Items.Add((string)rdr["GroupName"]);
}
```

Comment: It should be `while(rdr.Read())`

Comment: @Nacereddine: yes, you're right... just a typo, sorry. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the reader to the first row by calling `rdr.Read()`.

If there is no row to move to, `Read()` will return false.